# Trying to write a symbol to a file for python 3.6.0 but I'm getting errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I'm trying to add the symbol ฿ to a text file in Python 3.6.0 but I keep getting the error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0e3f'
    in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

I've also tried changing the `f.write('฿')` to `f.write('฿'.encode("\u0e3f"))` but I then receive the error:

```
LookupError: unknown encoding: ฿
```

I've attempted a few different ways but I'm still getting errors.  Is there something that I'm missing perhaps? Any tips/answers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please show your code.  Also, the way you're using `encode` doesn't make sense.  The argument to encode is the name of an encoding, something like `f.write('฿'.encode("utf-8"))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the output **file** encoding:

```
outstring = "฿"
with open("f:/toolbuild/temp/temp.txt", "wt", encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
    outfile.write(outstring)
```

works nicely!